# 2D array trouble finding char element(s)

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, char

I am trying to find the longest series of horizontal O's in my 2d array and just print out the longest path. I don't see my logic error, I keep reading over this but don't see my error. I have been stuck here for about 2 days. I am thinking maybe there is something wrong with my finding max length statement? I get an out of bounds error on line 58 and 31. Any advice to what I'm doing wrong would be much appreciated.

```
public class game {

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO code application logic here
    Scanner kbd = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("ENTER A SINGLE INTEGER: ");
    int n = kbd.nextInt();
    char[][] mazeValue = new char[n][n];
    System.out.println("ENTER A PATH: ");
    for(int i = 0; i < mazeValue.length; i++ ){
        for(int j = 0; j< mazeValue[i].length; j++){
            mazeValue[i][j]= kbd.next().charAt(0);
        }
    }
    printMaze(mazeValue);
    horizontalPath(mazeValue);
}
public static void printMaze(char mazeValue[][])
{
    System.out.println("MAZE");
    for(int i = 0; i < mazeValue.length; i ++)
 {
        for (int j = 0; j < mazeValue[i].length; j++)
        {
        System.out.printf("%4c",mazeValue[i][j]);
        }
     System.out.printf("\n");
   }
 }
 public static void horizontalPath(char mazeValue[][])
  {
   int horizontalPath=0;
   int maxHorizontalCount=0;
   int i;
   int j;
   for(i= 0; i<mazeValue.length; i++){
       for(j = 0; j<mazeValue[i].length; j++){
       if(mazeValue[i][j]== 'o'){
           horizontalPath = horizontalPath + mazeValue[i][j];
       }

     }
     if(horizontalPath < mazeValue[i][j])
         maxHorizontalCount = mazeValue[i][j];
   }
   System.out.printf("Longest horizontal path row %d length %d",i,maxHorizontalCount);
 }

}
```

Comment: Do you see any line numbers here? Please indicate where exactly these are happening.

Comment: the function call to : horizontalPath(); 31

Comment: the second if statement : if(horizontalPath < mazeValue[i][j]) 58

Comment: because on the line `if(horizontalPath < mazeValue[i][j])` you are outside of second for loop, so `j = mazeValue[i].length;` and that is outside of array

Comment: See thats how I had it, but the count is not working correctly so I just tried moving it outside the first if statement. Any idea why the length of the longest row keeps coming up 0??

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you have some imports before your code which offsets the line numbers, and your problem is in line 47 in the code above:

```
if(horizontalPath < mazeValue[i][j])
     maxHorizontalCount = mazeValue[i][j];
```

This block is *outside* of your for loop over j. This means that by the time control gets here, j will be equal to n, thus causing an index out of bounds.

Also note you're not actually computing a max value of anything, just setting maxHorizontalCount to the value at [i][j]. To compute a max, you should do something like

```
maxHorizontalCount = maxHorizontalCount > mazeValue[i][j] ? maxHorizontalCount : mazeValue[i][j];
```

or use Math.max() of course.